# Use macvlan to emulate multiple hardware devices on network

Tags: networking, iptables, ip, routing, macvlan

I am trying to use linux's network name spaces to emulate multiple devices on my local network. I want this to appear as actual network devices, not my laptops IP masquerading on the subnet. Is this possible?

[image]

I want to use these namespaces to launch a couple of bash scripts that have internet access, i.e:

```
sudo ip netns exec netns1 myscript1.sh
sudo ip netns exec netns2 myscript2.sh
```

I am working on a script to create the virtual network. At the moment I am only attempting to make on namespace:

```
INTERFACE=enp59s0
IP1=192.168.2.101/24

# create macvlan and associate it to network device in bride mode
ip link add macvlan1 link $INTERFACE type macvlan mode bridge

# create new network namespace
ip netns add netns1

# associate the macvlan to the new namespace
ip link set macvlan1 netns netns1

# Set IP address
ip -n netns1 addr add $IP1 dev macvlan1

# set macvlan to up
ip netns exec netns1 ifconfig macvlan1 up
```

This lets me ping devices within my subnet, i.e. the following works

```
sudo ip netns exec netns1 nmap -sn 192.168.2.1-255
```

However, when I cannot ping the virtual device from default namespace.

In addition, adding the router to route still does not let me connect to the outside world:

```
sudo ip netns exec netns1 ip route add default via 192.168.2.1
sudo ip netns exec netns1 ping 8.8.8.8

From 192.168.2.1 icmp_seq=1 Destination Net Unreachable
```

Any ideas?
Is this the right approach?

Would it be better to alias an IP with ifconfig:

`ifconfig enp59s0:0 192.168.2.101 up`

And then bind the new interface to a namespace somehow?